# android - How to download the images from the web and how to use int the app without getting the out of memory exception

Tags: android

I my application one issue is there. please suggest how to do it.
Issue: Downloading the images from the web and how to use it in the app.

1. For this , first i am downloading the images from the web and these images are stored in the sdcard dynamically. But here i am getting out of memory exception. one more problem is there it is not working in the mobiles which don't have sdcard.

Please suggest the better way how to do it. can any body help me.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had similar and mulitple problems, 
check my post ,
hope it helps:)
[Request time failed : java.net.socketexception : Address family not supported by protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301158/request-time-failed-java-net-socketexception-address-family-not-supported-by/7329797#7329797)

feel free to ask the doubts