# Reason why i'm not getting Json Response from server

Tags: android, json, android-json-rpc

```
 public  String POST(String url){
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";
        try {

            // 1. create HttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // 2. make POST request to the given URL
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            String json = "";

            // 3. build jsonObject
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.accumulate("UserName","example@gmail.com");
            jsonObject.accumulate("Password","123456!");
            jsonObject.accumulate("AppID","ANDAPP");

            // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
            json = jsonObject.toString();

            // ** Alternative way to convert Person object to JSON string usin Jackson Lib 
            // ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            // json = mapper.writeValueAsString(person); 

            // 5. set json to StringEntity
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

            // 6. set httpPost Entity
            httpPost.setEntity(se);

            // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content   
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext()," text",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // 9. receive response as inputStream
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            // 10. convert inputstream to string
            if(inputStream != null)
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            else
                result = "Did not work!";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        // 11. return result
        return result;
    }
 private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

         // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "post invoked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return POST(urls[0]);
        }
        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data Sent!"+result+" don", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
    }

 private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            result += line;

        inputStream.close();
        return result;

    }
```

I tried to invoke this POST method from an object of HTTPAsyncTask class, with targeted url passed. But the Toast execeuted in OnPostExecute() popping up with the message "Data sent!Done", which tells that value of 'result' variable is null. Why am i getting this? What would the fault? Could anyone please fix this.

Comment: Have you tried doind it in web

Comment: i am trying to acess it from android application

Comment: We will need the server code that handles the POST. May be the server is not returning any data. You should check the Status code of the response to know if it's OK(200) or if it's failing on server (5xx) or due to invalid client request (4xx).

Comment: @user2750644 pst post the convertInputStreamToString

Comment: @ M.Sameer how can i check status code?

Comment: `httpResponse.getStatus()`

Comment: @M.Sameer I'm getting feedback from logcat that "Request time failed,Java.net.socketException:Addres family not supported by protocol".

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301158/request-time-failed-java-net-socketexception-address-family-not-supported-by